# Update all rows in database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, bulk, content-values

What is the effective way to update all records in the database. I try to update all rows for the same key independent from table id, like this:

```
 for (int i = 0 ; i < rowsCount ; i++) {
      cv.put(column2, columnValue[i]);
      cv.put(column3, columnValue[i]);
      db.update(tableName, cv, null, null);
}
```

**Update:** I can't know the id values. The id values in the database looks like this: 1, 22, 50, 67 etc.

Comment: the first and the second answer of the link may work

Comment: I need solution independent from table id.

Comment: check my answer update, and say if it works please :)

Comment: I can not know the id value, therefore I need a solution to update all column cells independent from id.

Comment: So you need to update the table with insert into table independently of the id? Then just don't use the where statement like this:

Comment: String strSQL = "UPDATE theTable SET Column1 = someNewValue; myDataBase.execSQL(strSQL);

Comment: make me know if that worked please :)

Comment: What I did in my code, update all records with the same value. How can I add all columns values to the all records without using id.

Comment: Do you want to update all records?

Comment: Just do what i said, dont punt the where statement! :) see my last part of the answer and see this documentation: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp

Comment: This is your last part of your answer [WHERE Id = "+ someValueInStrType(someid);]. I said that I do not know the id, so I can not use your code.

Comment: Oh sorry, I edited the answer like 2 days ago but I didn't saved. Now the answer is updated, check it!

Comment: But this is easy to invoke  execSQL() for each value. What I meant, if there is an effective way to update all tables, that means with one call for execSQL or Database.update.

Answer (score 0):

### Updated:

```
String strSQL = "";

//Get the id that u want
String strSQL = "UPDATE theTable SET Column1 = someNewValue; UPDATE theTable SET Column1 = someNewValue;";
myDataBase.execSQL(strSQL);
```

Use ";" separator for each update that u want to introduce.

Comment: The solution here is depended on  whereClause. I have different id values, for example 1, 22, 50 etc.

Comment: The second link is for different keys that means for all columns in one row.